# Can't install ruby puma gem on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I installed [Ruby 2.3.3](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), [DevKit](https://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe) and [OpenSSL](http://packages.openknapsack.org/openssl/openssl-1.0.0k-x86-windows.tar.lzma) on Windows 7. [I followed the instruction to install puma](https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows#install-the-puma-gem), but I'm getting the error:

```
C:\Ruby23>gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\Ruby23\openssl
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        127: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/i386-mingw32/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

openssl.so is not compatible?

Comment: Although you already had openSSL installed I think you need to upgrade ruby before it was recognized.

Comment: @Roshan I had Ruby 2.4 installed, but had to downgraded to 2.3 because no mysql2 binary available for Ruby 2.4 for Windows.